# Transforming a function $f: \mathbb N^2 \to A$ to a function $f:\mathbb N\to A$ in a zig-zag manner

Tags: analysis, functions

We know that the rationals are countable since we can list them via zig-zagging:

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{1}   && \frac{1}{2} &\color{red}\to &\frac{1}{3} &&\frac{1}{4} & \color{red}\to & \frac{1}{5}\\
\color{red}\downarrow   & \color{red}\nearrow && \color{red}\swarrow && \color{red}\nearrow &&\color{red}\swarrow\\
\frac{2}{1}   && \frac{2}{2} && \frac{2}{3} \\
& \color{red}\swarrow && \color{red}\nearrow\\
\frac{3}{1}&&\frac{3}{2}&&& \ddots\\
\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\nearrow\\
\frac{4}{1}
\end{matrix}$$

Now suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb N^2 \to A$ for some set $A$, where we list the outputs of the function in the same way:
$$\begin{matrix}
f(1,1) && f(1,2) && f(1,3)  && f(1,4) && f(1,5)\\
~\\
f(2,1) && f(2,2) && f(2,3) \\
~\\
f(3,1) && f(3,2) &&& \ddots\\
~\\
f(4,1)
\end{matrix}$$

Is there a way to define a function $f' : \mathbb N \to A$ such the resulting sequence of outputs travels along this grid in the same way?

$$\begin{matrix}
f(1,1)   && f(1,2) &\color{red}\to &f(1,3) &&f(1,4)& \color{red}\to & f(1,5)\\
\color{red}\downarrow   & \color{red}\nearrow && \color{red}\swarrow && \color{red}\nearrow &&\color{red}\swarrow\\
f(2,1)   && f(2,2) && f(2,3) \\
& \color{red}\swarrow && \color{red}\nearrow\\
f(3,1) && f(3,2) &&& \ddots\\
\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\nearrow\\
f(4,1)
\end{matrix}$$

That is, defining $f'$ in terms of $f$ such that

$$ f'(1) = f(1,1)\\
f'(2) = f(2,1) \\
f'(3) = f(1,2) \\
f'(4) = f(1,3) \\
f'(5) = f(2,2) \\
f'(6) = f(3,1) \\
 \vdots$$

Given $n\in\mathbb N$ I need to find a way to map to the corresponding pair in $\mathbb N^2$, expressing this only in terms of $n$, but I'm not sure how to do this. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of ranking i.e.

*What is the point with rank $n$ ?*

Ranking (a mathematical art arising from Computer Science) is the fact of putting (denumerable) sets (say $X$, seen as a set of data structures) in explicit bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. Two problems then arise for the bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to X$ (here $X=\mathbb{N}^2$)

*A) Given $P\in X$, what is the "rank" of $P$ (i.e. $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $g(n)=P$) ?*

*B) Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ what is the "position of $P$" ?*

If you draw your picture, you see that the visits of your zig-zag 
curve (starting with $\phi(0)=(0,0),\phi(1)=(1,0)$) to the $x$-axis are for 
$n=0,1,5,6,14,15$ then for points $(2n^2+3n,2n^2+3n+1)$. Now your pattern 
is clear in 4 paragraphs.

a) Visits to $x$-axis 
$$
\phi(2n^2+3n)=(2n,0)\ ;\ \phi(2n^2+3n+1)=(2n+1,0) 
$$ 
b) Transition $x$-axis to $y$-axis
$$
\phi(2n^2+3n+1+k)=(2n+1-k,k)\ ;\ k=0\ldots 2n+1 
$$
c) Visits to $y$-axis
$$
\phi(2n^2+5n+2)=(0,2n+1)\ ;\ \phi(2n^2+5n+3)=(0,2n+2) 
$$ 
d) Transition $y$-axis to $x$-axis
$$
\phi(2n^2+5n+3+k)=(k,2n+2-k)\ ;\ k=0\ldots 2n+2 
$$
and again because your reach the $x$-axis at rank 
$$
2n^2+5n+3+2n+2=2(n+1)^2+3(n+1)
$$ 
and return to (a) section.

Now, giving a rank $N$, to know $\phi(N)$ amounts to position $N$ w.r.t. the following sectors 
$$
2n^2+3n<2n^2+3n+1<\cdots <2n^2+5n+2<2n^2+5n+3<\cdots <2(n+1)^2+3(n+1)
$$
The positioning can be achieved solving $2n^2+3n-N=0$ and taking the integer part, here 
$$
n=\lfloor\frac{-3+\sqrt{9+8N}}{4}\rfloor\ .
$$

**Late edit** Above is just to show you in detail where the ideas came from. If you have to compactly answer to the *ranking* question ($B$), you can, for instance, use the piecewise description of Milo (with $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$). Having to compute $g(N)$, you first compute 
$$
n=\lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+9N}}{2}\rfloor\ .
$$ 
you then get $k=N-T_n$ and can apply the dichotomy. If you are chasing the single formula you can even have one with "commutators".

**Late late edit** Here is, just for the fun, my version of commutators ; first use [Iverson_bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) to write $g$ and then (I use here [[??]] in order to differentiate it from maths) convert Iverson brackets as follows 
$$
[[k\mbox{ is odd}]]=k-2\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor\ ;\ 
[[k\mbox{ is even}]]=1-k+2\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor\ .
$$

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing here. Can you clarify a bit what you did near the end? And what exactly do you mean by the term *rank*?

Comment: I elaborated a bit the concept of "ranking". Do not hesitate to interact.

Comment: @LukeCollins [I think I understand what you are doing here.]--->I wanted to show you in detail where the ideas came from.

Comment: @LukeCollins If you find my contribution helpful do not hesitate to vote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly. In particular, the idea of "zig-zagging" is captured by defining a bijection
$$g:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N^2$$
where $g(i)$ is the $i^{th}$ element in the zig-zag. Then, you are looking for the function
$$f'=f\circ g.$$
That is, the function defined as $f'(x)=f(g(x))$. Essentially, you are using $g$ to determine the input to $f$, which causes it to zig-zag through the outputs as you desire. This actually gives you a bijection between the set of functions $\mathbb N^2\rightarrow A$ and the set of functions $\mathbb N\rightarrow A$.

You could write $g$ explicitly if you wanted to. For instance, if we let $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}2=1+\ldots+n$ be the $n^{th}$ triangular number. We could express $g$ by saying, for $0\leq k \leq n$
$$g(T_n+k)=\begin{cases}(n-k,k) & \text{if }n\text{ odd}\\
(k,n-k) & \text{if }n\text{ even.}
\end{cases}$$
This assumes you consider $0\in \mathbb N$, but it's easy enough to shift everything to make it work if you don't like zero being a natural number.

---

If we wanted to write $g$ in a single equation, we could do so. In particular, suppose we want to know $g(x)$. We can figure this out based on the previous equation. We first must write $x=T_n+k$, so must determine $n$ and $k$. In particular, $T_n=\frac{1}2(n+1/2)^2-\frac{1}8$, so we can write $n=\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor.$ Then, $k=x-T_n$. We can also write our expression as
$$g(T_n+k)=\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^n+1}2\cdot n + (-1)^nk\right),\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+1}2\cdot n + (-1)^{n+1}k\right)\right).$$
Then, blindly substituting everything in gives:
$$g(x)=\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor}+1}2\cdot (\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor)+(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor}\cdot (x+1/8-\frac{1}2(\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor)^2\right),\left(\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor+1}+1}2\cdot (\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor)+(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor+1}\cdot (x+1/8-\frac{1}2(\lfloor\sqrt{2x+1/4}-1/2\rfloor)^2\right)\right).$$
However, I think it should be fairly clear why I prefer the other way of writing this function. Note that if we want $\mathbb N$ to not include zero, we have to replace every instance of $n$ in the above formula by $n-1$ and then add one to each coordinate afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a more explicit way of defining $g$, perhaps not in a piece-wise manner?

Comment: @LukeCollins The answer to that depends on what you mean by "explicit" -
 I think this is the clearest way to write $g$. If, however, you want a single formula, it is certainly *possible* if you're okay with using the floor function and raising $(-1)$ to integer powers. (I could write this if you wish, but it wouldn't look pretty)

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you write it down!

Comment: @LukeCollins I added the formula. (It doesn't fit very well on the page, but I don't think it can be shortened very much. It's rather redundant - it's much easier to calculate $n$ from $x$, then $k$ from $x$ and $n$, then use the original formula)